# Set Date Format in Variable

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

Just wondering if anyone can help me setting a date variable for a report to run between certain dates every year without needing to be updated manually.

For example, I have the dates hard-coded below, but I was wondering if I could set a date format for when it goes into 2017 that the dates will change for the 2017 year. I presume there is a way to set a yearly date format I am just not sure how.

This is my hard-coded variables I set.
Put in the wrong Date Ranges changed as below.

```
set @start_date =   '2016-01-02';
set @end_date = '2017-01-01';
```

Below is what I have in my where clause also.

```
and create_date between  @start_date and  @end_date
```

Comment: **avoid** using `between` for date ranges, see https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common or https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/11210/Beware-of-Between.html

Answer (score 0):

Your range covers all days in the year, except *January 1*. So you can simply check the day and month:

```
WHERE NOT (DAY(create_date) = 1 AND MONTH(create_date) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
declare @s datetime, @e datetime
set @s=cast(cast(year(getdate()) as char(4))+'-01-02' as date)
set @e=cast(cast(year(getdate()) as char(4))+'-12-31' as date)
select @s,@e
```

Answer (score 0):

set @start_date = CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS nvarchar(4)) + '0102' AS DATETIME);

to get end of current year

SET @end_date = DATEADD(day, -1 , DATEADD(month,13 - MONTH(getdate()), DATEADD(day,1 - DAY(getdate()),getdate())));

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the FULL "current year" based on "today"

---

MySQL

```
select * 
from whatever
where ( create_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01')
   and  create_date <  CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())+1,'-01-01')
      )
```

Test it with:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01')   This_year_start
, CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())+1,'-01-01') Next_year_start
```

---

SQL Server (tsql)

```
select * 
from whatever
where ( create_date >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,  0, GETDATE()), 0)
   and  create_date <  DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
      )
```

Test it with:

```
select
  DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) , 0) This_year_start
, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()), 0) Next_year_start

    This_year_start     Next_year_start
    01.01.2016 00:00:00 01.01.2017 00:00:00
```

- DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) calculates the number of years from the
  base year
- add that number of years to the base date (1900-01-01)
- DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) calculates the number of years from
  year before the base year (is a bigger number, by 1, than above)
- add that number of years to the base date (1900-01-01)

---

Please **avoid** using `between` for date ranges. It is far safer to use a combination of >= and <

e.g.
where create_date >= '2016-01-01' and create_date < '2017-01-01'

With that approach, no matter what time precsion applies to the data in [create_date] you will get the precise range of information requested.